# Get current country of user not with the IP address

Tags: php, geolocation

I try to explain my problem: the customers of my site are usually tourists who book in advance from their country or last-minute when they are already here. In order to offer last-minute offers to users who are already here and not to those who are at home I use a PHP script that recognizes the location via the IP address.

So far no problem, only that many users connected over mobile phone networks (roaming) have IP addresses assigned by their phone companies and located in their countries, so they will never see the offer I want to show them.

I've already thought of inserting a script that asks for geolocation through their device, but I want to avoid this annoying request that many would not accept for obvious privacy issues. In short, it is always important to make navigation fast and pleasant to encourage confidence.

does anyone have a good suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the geolocation API.

Just as an example...

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
   });
} else {
  /* geolocation IS NOT available */
}
```

reference from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API

According with Site Point: https://www.sitepoint.com/browser-geolocation/ this browsers have support.

- Firefox 3.5+
- Chrome 5.0+
- Safari 5.0+
- Opera 10.60+
- Internet Explorer 9.0+

Comment: 90% of users use mobile browsers like safari and chrome, it would not change much I think

Comment: according with https://www.sitepoint.com/browser-geolocation/  Firefox 3.5+ Chrome 5.0+ Safari 5.0+ Opera 10.60+ Internet Explorer 9.0+ have support.